# How to Navigate to another component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a functional component. I've tried using react router's useHistory. I'm trying to click a button and navigate to a new react component (screen or view).

```
function App() {
      const history = useHistory();
      function handleClick() {
        history.push("/UserList");
      }

  return (
    <div>
     
      <form>
        <br/>
        <label>user name: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)}/><br />
        <br/>
        <label>password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" onClick={() => handleCredentials}/>
      </form>
    
      
      <button onClick={handleClick}>User List</button>


    </div>
  );
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: Try going through the documentation and implementing examples. It will help you learn and build on your knowledge.

Comment: Check react-router-dom docs, to implement router.

Comment: Are you actually implementing react-router in your code? Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check what is you react router version. If its v6 then use useNavigation instead of useHistory. And there are changes to Switch,Route and more, but that you will find in docs.